# Need sample E-commerce order data

Tags: data-request, business, analysis

Is there any sample data for Ecommerce orders? What I need is Order no, Customer details, address, ratings by same customer, delivery times etc.

I need it this for data analysis project i am doing. These need not be really true, like the names and addresses of people can be fictional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A popular answer comes from a 2010 question on Stackoverflow - [Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3647873/2327328)

- [Northwind database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2036395/2327328) - ([documentation & data model](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/))
- [NopCommerce sample dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660733/2327328)
- [E-commerce dataset from Amazon / Google Products / Abt Buy](http://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/en/research/projects/object_matching/fever/benchmark_datasets_for_entity_resolution)

Other ideas:

- [Tableau Superstore (Excel file)](http://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236) (although I think this is aggregated)